# C programming Segmentation fault: 11 Thread issues

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, segmentation-fault, fault

Why does this error occur when I run my code?
error: `RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault: 11; real time: 3s; user: 0ms; system: 0m`

I'm creating 10 threads where each thread is a ticket seller. There is a 10by10 array that holds the seats of the tickets. Depending on the type of the ticket-seller a person will be sold that specific seat.

Is the issue with the pthreads?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   ticketsellers.c
 * Author: iantheflyinghawaiian
 *
 * Created on July 4, 2016, 11:27 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// seller thread to serve one time slice (1 minute)

int theatre[10][10] ;

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *ptr;
}*front,*rear,*temp,*front1;

int count = 0;

/* Create an empty queue */
void create()
{
    front = rear = NULL;
}

/* Returns queue size */
void queuesize()
{
    printf("\n Queue size : %d", count);
}

/* Enqueing the queue */
void enq(int data)
{
    if (rear == NULL)
    {
        rear = (struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        rear->ptr = NULL;
        rear->info = data;
        front = rear;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        rear->ptr = temp;
        temp->info = data;
        temp->ptr = NULL;

        rear = temp;
    }
    count++;
}

/* Displaying the queue elements */
void display()
{
    front1 = front;

    if ((front1 == NULL) && (rear == NULL))
    {
        printf("Queue is empty");
        return;
    }
    while (front1 != rear)
    {
        printf("%d ", front1->info);
        front1 = front1->ptr;
    }
    if (front1 == rear)
        printf("%d", front1->info);
}

/* Dequeing the queue */
void deq()
{
    front1 = front;

    if (front1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error: Trying to display elements from empty queue");
        return;
    }
    else
        if (front1->ptr != NULL)
        {
            front1 = front1->ptr;
            printf("\n Dequed value : %d", front->info);
            free(front);
            front = front1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n Dequed value : %d", front->info);
            free(front);
            front = NULL;
            rear = NULL;
        }
        count--;
}

/* Returns the front element of queue */
int frontelement()
{
    if ((front != NULL) && (rear != NULL))
        return(front->info);
    else
        return 0;
}

/* Display if queue is empty or not */
void empty()
{
     if ((front == NULL) && (rear == NULL))
        printf("\n Queue empty");
    else
       printf("Queue not empty");
}



//Ticket Seller
void * sell(char *seller_type)
{
    char seller_type1;
    seller_type1 = *seller_type;
    int i;
    i = 0;
 while (i == 0);
 {
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 // Serve any buyer available in this seller queue that is ready
 // now to buy ticket till done with all relevant buyers in their queue
 //………………
 // Case statements for seller_types
    switch(seller_type1)
    {
        case 'H' :
            printf("Seller type: H\n");
            i = 1;
            break;
        case 'M' :
            printf("Seller type: M\n");
            i = 1;
            break;
        case 'L' :
            printf("Seller type: L\n");
            i = 1;
            break;
    }
 }
 return NULL; // thread exits
}
void wakeup_all_seller_threads()
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
int main()
{
 int i, N;
 pthread_t tids[10];
 printf("Enter N value of Customers: ");
 scanf("%d", &N);
 printf("Number of Customers: %d", N);

 char seller_type;
 // Create necessary data structures for the simulator.
 // Create buyers list for each seller ticket queue based on the
 // N value within an hour and have them in the seller queue.
 // Create 10 threads representing the 10 sellers.
 seller_type = 'H';
 pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type);
 seller_type = 'M';

 for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
 pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type);
 seller_type = 'L';
 for (i = 4; i < 10; i++)
 pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type);
 // wakeup all seller threads
 wakeup_all_seller_threads();

 // wait for all seller threads to exit
 for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    pthread_join(&tids[i], NULL);
 // Printout simulation results
 //…………
 exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault is accessing read-only memory, accessing not accessible memory, accessing null pointer, and so on

Comment: Why did you include a bunch of code that isn't used at all?

Comment: Each thread is going to have its own queue where "customers" we'll be waiting to buy tickets. That's why the code isn't used at all at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already assumed by @2501: the culprit causing the segfault was the uninitialized variable `i` in `main`.

I took the liberty to write a minimal example for your pthread-creating, with the addition of some printf`s.

It compiles without warnings with

`gcc -W -Wall threadtest.c -o threadtest -pthread`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct seller_type {
  char st;
  int tid;
};

void *sell(void *arg)
{
  struct seller_type *seller_type1 = arg;
  int i;
  i = 0;
  printf("thread #%d: seller_type1->st = %c\n", seller_type1->tid,
     seller_type1->st);
  // no semicolon after while()
  while (i == 0) {
    switch (seller_type1->st) {
    case 'H':
      printf("Seller type: H\n");
      i = 1;
      break;
    case 'M':
      printf("Seller type: M\n");
      i = 1;
      break;
    case 'L':
      printf("Seller type: L\n");
      i = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("thread #%d: Work done\n", seller_type1->tid);
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  struct seller_type *seller_type1;

  pthread_t tids[10];

  seller_type1 = calloc(10, sizeof(struct seller_type));
  // All error handling ommitted! Yes, ALL!

  seller_type1[0].st = 'H';
  seller_type1[0].tid = 0;
  pthread_create(&tids[0], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[0]);

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    seller_type1[i].st = 'M';
    seller_type1[i].tid = i;
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[i]);
  }

  for (i = 4; i < 10; i++) {
    seller_type1[i].st = 'L';
    seller_type1[i].tid = i;
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[i]);
  }
  puts("All threads created");

  // wait for all seller threads to exit
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    printf("Thread %d joined\n", i);
  }
  puts("All threads joined");

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I hope you can build upon that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a data race when you pass `seller_type` to the newly created thread, while at the same time modify the variable in the main.

The type of the function passed to `pthread_create` must be: `void*(*)(void*)`, not the type you're using.

Function `pthread_join` requires a type `pthread_t` as the first argument, not a pointer to that type, which is what you're passing to it.

The variable `i` in the main isn't initialized, and is used to index the array `tids`, in the first pthread_create call.

All of those four problems cause undefined behavior by themselves. I suspect the last one causes the crash.

Comment: hi 2501, 

I corrected pthread_join, and initialized i. How do I correct the pthread_create function to be able to pass the seller_type to the sell thread?